# In Laravel 5.6, is it necessary to check if a directory exists before creation? (Situational)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

In a function used in Image Storage, I realized I MAY have been over-complicating the code.  I have two examples that both return the same results.

**First Example:**

```
    public function image(Request $request, User $user)
    {
      $file = $request->file('image');  

      $path = "user_" . $user->id . "_images";

      $filename = $path . "/test.jpg";

      Storage::disk('public')->put($filename, File::get($file));

      return back();
    }
```

This example was tested in two scenarios.  Once with NO directory inside public, and it returned by creating ***public/user_1_images/test.jpg*** ...

The second scenario, we already had ***public/user_1_images/*** as an empty directory.  Meaning it already exists.  So instead, it just put the file inside of there without creating the folder.

**Second Example:**

```
    public function image(Request $request, User $user)
    {
      $file = $request->file('image');  

      $path = "user_" . $user->id . "_images";

      if (!Storage::disk('public')->exists($path)) 
      {
          Storage::makeDirectory($path, 0755, true, true);
      }

      $filename = $path . "/test.jpg";

      Storage::disk('public')->put($filename, File::get($file));

      return back();

}
```

In this example, we're checking to see if public/user_1_images/ exists, and if it does not, we're creating the folder, and then putting the image inside.

Would I need to do this, if I can just have it automatically check/create/not-create by titling the file "user_1_images/test.jpg"?

Comment: it cannot be done automatically, you should check if directory exist like you do in second example. whats the problem with it? if you want to reduce code, move your check/create in helper function, and call it before upload

Comment: I'm saying it does do it automatically if I sell the file name to 'user_1_images/test.jpg', even if I delete the directory, it creates it again and puts the file in it, without the check & makeDirectory functions.  I have no problem with the extra few lines, I just don't understand why I should if it is truly doing it automatically, which I've verified it does.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the driver you use. All drivers must implement **AdapterInterface** interface and that's the only requirement they must meet.

I had a brief look at some of the popular drivers:

- **Local** driver always calls **ensureDirectory()** before writing to a path, hence there is no need to create directory manually.
- **FTP** driver always calls **ensureDirectory()** before writing to a path, hence there is no need to create directory manually.
- **S3** driver doesn't ensure a directory exist, but all necessary directories are created in S3 when it's asked to write to a path that contains directories. So again, no need to create directory manually.

So it seems that with most (if not all) drivers you can simply write to a path and not worry whether directory exists or not.